# Entity framework Modify multiple records with common data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an "Apps" Table which consists of multiple apps data
Now I wanted to delete (soft delete means making isDelete = true)

I'm deleting records by the following code.

```
var deletingISVCSPRecord = await db.ISVCSP.Where(s => s.BeneficiaryId == beneficiaryId).ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in deletingISVCSPRecord)
{
    item.IsDeleted = true;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

is there any good way to do this.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this not working?

Comment: Working as expected but we are iterating matching records and updating database so the problem is if we have a 1000's of records we may get the performance issue right? so is there any good way to modify common data in matching records like(we have a range keyword to delete all records between 1-10)

Answer (score 0):

Better way means if you updating around 10k record this is the better way.. it will reduce each single file updating into one shot updating.

```
foreach (var item in db.ISVCSP.Where(s => s.BeneficiaryId == beneficiaryId))
{
    item.IsDeleted = true;    
}
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have been doing is to use transaction scope and only save once after all the updates. This has worked fine enough for me on my projects so far, you might want to do a comparison on whichever is more efficient tho.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
     db.ISVCSP.Where(s => s.BeneficiaryId == beneficiaryId).ForEach(item =>
     {
          item.IsDeleted = true; 
     });
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be Update the Records not to Delete Totally

Assuming that you have already created a Model name `ISVCSPModel`

```
ISVCSPModel ISVCSPmodel= db.ISVCSP.Find(beneficiaryId)
db.Entry(ISVCSPmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
ISVCSPmodel.IsDeleted = true;
db.SaveChangesAsync();
```